# Check if File exists before running a query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am a newbie so forgive my ignorance;

I have an upload PDF form that I check if the form already exists, if it doesnt, I upload it and would therefore like to run a mysql insert query. I tried this:

```
if (file_exists($pdfSubDirectory.$filename))
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $quer->execute();
    }
```

but I get the error;

***> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object***

any ideas?

my main code is;

```
    <?php
require "config.php";

$cat        = $_GET['cat1'];
$catid      = $_GET['cat'];
$subcat     = $_GET['subcat'];
$subcatid   = $_GET['subcatid'];
$subcat2    = $_GET['subcat2'];

//form vars
$form_class = $_POST['Class']; // create modify delete flag
$form_cerfa = $_POST['Cerfa']; // cerfa Yes or No flag
$form_id = $_POST['ID'];
$form_name = $_POST['Name'];

$predir = "./docs";
$dir = $predir."/" .$cat. "/" .$subcat."/" .$subcat2 . "/";
$dir= strtolower($dir);
$dir= str_replace(' ', '_', $dir);


$MyHtml1 = <<<EOD

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>$subcat / $subcat2</title>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 50%;">You are in the category:</td>
                                    <td style="width: 50%;">$cat</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>You are in the subcategory:</td>
                                    <td>$subcat</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>You are in section:</td>
                                    <td>$subcat2</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <p>Time:</p>

                        <p>Date:</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                        <hr />
                        <p>...</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

EOD;

echo $MyHtml1;
$pdfDirectory = $dir;
$pdfSubDirectory = $pdfDirectory.$_POST['Class']."/";
$thumbDirectory = $pdfDirectory . "pdfimage/";
$filename = basename( $_FILES['pdf']['name'], ".pdf");
$filename = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/", "", $filename).".pdf";
$thumb = basename($filename, ".pdf");

if (file_exists($pdfSubDirectory.$filename)) {
    echo "This file already exists.";
} else {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $pdfSubDirectory.$filename)) {

    //the path to the PDF file
    $pdfWithPath = $pdfDirectory.$filename;
    $pdfWithSubPath = $pdfSubDirectory.$filename;
    $pdfWithPathImage = $pdfDirectory."pdfimage/";
    $pdfWithPathImageThumb = $pdfWithPathImage.$thumb.".jpg";
    //add the desired extension to the thumbnail
    $thumb = $thumb.".jpg";

    //execute imageMagick's 'convert', setting the color space to RGB and size to 200px wide
    //exec("convert \"{$pdfWithSubPath}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 100 $thumbDirectory$thumb");
    exec("convert  -density 200 -page 792x612 \"{$pdfWithSubPath}[0]\" -append -resize 240 -background white -flatten +repage $thumbDirectory$thumb");   
    //show the image
    echo "<p><a href=\"$pdfWithPath\"><img src=".$pdfWithPathImageThumb." alt=\"\" /></a></p>";
    echo $pdfWithPathImageThumb;
        }
}
if (isset(file_exists($pdfSubDirectory.$filename)))
    {
      $quer->execute();
    }



///////// start of query for form addition//////////
$quer = $dbo -> prepare("INSERT into form_detail(form_id,form_name,form_category,form_subcategory,form_subcategory2,form_class,form_cerfa) VALUES(:form_id,:form_name,:form_category,:form_subcategory,:form_subcategory2,:form_class,:form_cerfa)");
$quer ->bindParam(':form_id', $form_id);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_name', $form_name);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_category', $catid);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_subcategory', $subcatid);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_subcategory2', $subcat2);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_class', $form_class);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_cerfa', $form_cerfa);

///////////// End of query for form addition////////////


$MyHtml2 = <<<EOD

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="MyForm">
        <input type="file" name="pdf" /><br>

           <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Cerfa : </label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Cerfa" value="1" checked="checked"/>Yes<input type="radio" name="Cerfa" value="0"/>No<br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Form Class: </label></td>
            <td><select name="Class">
            <option value="create">Create</option>
            <option value="modify">Modify</option>
            <option value="delete">Delete</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <label>Form Name: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Name" value="Name"/><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Form Reference No : </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ID" value="Reference Number"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Check details and upload</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



</form>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 937px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <p>Forms Available</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 44px; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 228px;">Ref</td>
            <td rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 89px;">Cerfa</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 595px;">Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 228px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td rowspan="1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>

EOD;

echo $MyHtml2;

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir."create/"));

while($it->valid()) {

    if (!$it->isDot()) {

        echo 'File Name: ' . $it->getSubPathName() . "\n<br>";
    }

    $it->next();
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is $quer defined?

Comment: Can you show that code?

Comment: why a -1 vote? was it a really stupid question?

Comment: You are using $quer before you define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare `$quer` before executing it. Put this code...

```
///////// start of query for form addition//////////
$quer = $dbo -> prepare("INSERT into form_detail(form_id,form_name,form_category,form_subcategory,form_subcategory2,form_class,form_cerfa) VALUES(:form_id,:form_name,:form_category,:form_subcategory,:form_subcategory2,:form_class,:form_cerfa)");
$quer ->bindParam(':form_id', $form_id);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_name', $form_name);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_category', $catid);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_subcategory', $subcatid);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_subcategory2', $subcat2);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_class', $form_class);
$quer ->bindParam(':form_cerfa', $form_cerfa);
///////////// End of query for form addition////////////
```

Above this:

```
if (file_exists($pdfSubDirectory.$filename))
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $quer->execute();
    }
```

When the script is ran, it gets to the `if (file_exists($pdfSubDirectory.$filename))`, finds it true, and tries to execute a query that doesn't exist.

Comment: the error has gone but it adds it to the mysql table regardless

Comment: any ideas on how to stop adding it if the form exists?

Comment: Wait, stop adding if the form DOES exist? If that is what you want, change the if condition to `if (!file_exists($pdfSubDirectory.$filename))`

Comment: the process is select file, click upload, it check IF it exists it says 'file exists ELSE it adds it and should then add the form details to the mysql table

Comment: at the moment, it adds nothing, even if it exists or it doesnt

Comment: I found the answer, I deleted the if (file_exists($pdfSubDirectory.$filename))
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $quer->execute();
    } and placed $quer->execute(); after the line echo $pdfWithPathImageThumb;